# Pass the selected listbox value as variable in the VBA module in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I am doing it for first time
I know asking an easy question. Couldnt figure it out on google
I have a access form that have a combo box and list box, Based on the combox box value selected user List box shows a set of values, I want the user selected (The one which users selected) value in the list box to go as variable inside the seperate module.I tried something like

```
ListTable = Me.Linked_Table_List.ListIndex

ListTable = Me.Linked_Table_List.Value
```

and many more iteration but nothing is working

I want to used the value in listtable to go into another module. I have declared listTable as Global

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Using "Me" will only work within the form's module. If you need to reference this in another VBA module, you'd need to use "Forms!*MyForm*!Linked_Table_List". Note that you don't need to specify the property "Value" as it's the default for listboxes, textboxes, combos etc.

Comment: ListTable = [Form]![Combo box]![Linked_Table_List]!.Value

Comment: Is your form called "Combo Box"? 

Note too, that you have a typo before "Value", you have "!." - should be just "!" . And, it should be Forms, not Form.

Comment: Yes my form name is combox box, Got that Max Thanks